# how to tar with a prefix directory

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

I want to tar the directory /opt/mydir
into a directory /opt/myprefix/mydir

how can I do that with tar command? (solaris)

thanks

Comment: What do you want to accomplish that won't be done with `cd /opt; mkdir myprefix; mv mydir myprefix`?

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate on ServerFault.

Comment: You can ask this on superuser or serverfault, but I think you'll find the answer prior to asking :) Sorry, but off topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a symlink so that you can access /opt/mydir as /opt/myprefix/mydir

```
cd /opt
ln -s . myprefix
```

Then tar it:

```
tar -cvf mytar.tar /opt/myprefix/mydir
```

Comment: is there no option to do that with tar command itself?

Comment: There is: http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/transform.html

Comment: this is from tar help, but I didn't test it: Prepend ‘/prefix/’ to each file name: `$ tar --transform 's,^,/prefix/,' -x -f arch.tar`

Comment: --transform is unsupported on older tar versions, original solution is a good workaround.